# How could I pass data to chart.js with flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I recently trying to make dashboard which datas from mongodb with flask. But I cannot send datas to chart.js. I got the data from mongodb and send to javascript and try to loop data with jinja2.

```
@app.route("/dashboard")
def dashboard():
    limit = request.args.get("limit",12,type=int)
    dashboardDatas = mongo.db.dashBoard
    dashDatas = dashboardDatas.find().limit(limit)

    return render_template("dashboard.html", dashDatas = dashDatas)
```

```
        <canvas id="myChart" height="50"></canvas>

        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: [ {% for item in dashDatas %} 
                                '{{item._id}}', 
                                {% endfor %} ],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [ {% for item in dashDatas %}
                                {{item.logistic}},
                                {% endfor %}],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 0.5
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
            </script>
```

And I got empty chart. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have a little knowledge in python, usually in js for loop is used for iterating it won't be return an array back, i feel like that can you check it

Comment: Just try instead of looping pass the datasets and labels as array something like this, and create the array in python code .
  => return render_template("dashboard.html", dashDatas = dashDatas, labels = labels, datasets = datasets)

Comment: It would help if you attach the generated HTML.

Comment: Can you please include the output of `print(dashDatas)`  (pastebin link if long)

Answer (score 7):

My approach is to store the labels and data in lists in the Flask view, pass them to the template and transform them to JSON with the `tojson` filter.

Suppose you have `labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `data = [1, 2, 3]` in your view. You can pass them to Chart.js in your template as

```js
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: {{ labels|tojson }},
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My 1st dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: {{ data|tojson }}
  }]
});
```

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer so that others can find it as well?

Comment: What would be the solution if you want to have a `.js` file separately? This jinja template is only supported in html files I assume.

Comment: You would include your file in a `<script>` tag in your template and pass the therein defined list to ChartJS `data` key. Make sure that your `.js` file is loaded before you reference or you'll end up with an empty chart.

Answer (score 0):

Version (library) 1 of chartjs has important differences to version 2 in terms of usability. Fine references are:
. version 1: https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2017/12/14/graphing-pretty-charts-with-python-flask-and-chartjs/
. version 2: https://towardsdatascience.com/flask-and-chart-js-tutorial-i-d33e05fba845