# Passing data from Python to JavaScript to plot Chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, html, chart.js

I want to know what the best practice is for my application project.

I want to render a chart using `Chart.js`. Data is generated in Python, and I know how to pass it to html: `render_template("/index.html", chart_data=chart_data)`. However, after passing `chart_data` to html, I don't know how to pass it to the javascript, where the chart is generated. Or, is it better to pass it directly from `.py` to `.js`, without bypassing `.html`? If so, what is the way?

Here are my codes:
app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    chart_data = {
        "labels": ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"],
        "values": [55, 49, 44, 24, 15]
    }
    return render_template("/index.html", chart_data=chart_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/app.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
// For the testing purpose, I generated the same data in js. 
// But I want to fetch this from .html, or directly from .py.
var xValues = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"];
var yValues = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15];
var barColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "brown"];

let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let barChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "population",
                data: yValues
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

As a side note, this is a minimal reproducible example from my entire project. In the real project, my `app.py` gets user inputs from `index.html` using `request.form.get()` and dynamically generates `chart_data`. But I excluded this part from the question because I was able to make it work.

**EDIT**
In the `app.js`, I modified like below but it seems this syntax is only supported in `.html`. I don't want to include my js script in html, but instead have it as a separated `.js` file.

```
data: {
        labels: {{ chart_data['labels']| tojson }},
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "population",
            data: {{ chart_data['values']| tojson }}
                }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I pass data to chart.js with flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874084/how-could-i-pass-data-to-chart-js-with-flask)

Comment: thanks for the direction. Yes it answers but partly. What if I don't want to include my javascript code in `.html` file but instead have a separated `.js` file? I modified my `.js`file to `labels: {{ chart_data['labels']| tojson }}` and `data: {{ chart_data['values']| tojson }}` but it seems this syntax is only supported in html fiels.

Comment: That's what APIs are for.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Could you elaborate more? @JishanShaikh

Comment: Instead of posting your data from python to HTML, you can directly transfer the data (preferably in JSON) to JavaScript using a custom API. You'll have to write an API and host it.

Comment: @Jishan Flask is already running an API

Comment: @Mako You can use `<script src="file.js">` for example rather than embedding within the html directly, like you've already done, however it can't be templated with Jinja braces

Answer (score 1):

The data should come from HTTP calls; doesn't really matter where that is, but it's not directly from HTML or a ".py file". Since you're using Flask and the data could be dynamic, you would add a route for it, not render it statically

```
# assume this is defined somewhere else, like a database 
chart_data = {
        "labels": ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"],
        "values": [55, 49, 44, 24, 15]
    } 

@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def data():
    global chart_data
    return jsonify(chart_data)
```

Then, you need a JS file that is loaded to call `fetch` API to get the data, and build the chart

```
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

fetch('http://127.0.0.1/data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
       console.log(data);
       let labels = data.labels; 
       let barChart = new Chart(myChart, {  
           ... 
   });
```

Then you include the JS file in a template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js'}}"/>
```

[Link to Flask static files with url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/)